# How to conditionally PopAsync based on what page is currently show to user

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Within the same page of my app the user can send off two websocket requests. That I then get two websocket responses. In each of those responses I pop the page from the nav stack. This is in their profile page where they can edit some basic info or change their password. Hopefully they usually would only do one but in the chance they do both and click save then it pops the page twice.

I have been trying to check the current page and if they are still on the profile page to go ahead and pop it but if they are not then skip the popping.

It seems like popasync is not actually removing the page from the stack because I will call the nav stack to a list afterwards to check and it's still there. I tried doing a check if any pages in the stack were the profile pages to then pop it. That still could be sloppy incase there were multiple instances of it in the stack but it would atleast get me in the right direction.

I also tried using MessagingCenter to bring it back to the code behind but that didn't do the trick either.

The main problem here is I only want to pop the page if that is the page the user is currently looking at.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

```
else if (root.payload?.data?.updateUserFields != null)
                {
                    DabGraphQlUpdateUserFields fields = root.payload.data.updateUserFields;

                    dbSettings.StoreSetting("Email", fields.email);
                    dbSettings.StoreSetting("FirstName", fields.firstName);
                    dbSettings.StoreSetting("LastName", fields.lastName);

                    GlobalResources.WaitStop();
                    var UserName = GlobalResources.GetUserName().Split(' ');
                    GuestStatus.Current.UserName = GlobalResources.GetUserName();
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "User profile information has been updated", "OK"); ; });
                    DabProfileManagementPage profilePage = new DabProfileManagementPage();
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Any(p => p is DabProfileManagementPage))
                        {
                            var existingPagess = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
                            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                            var _lastPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
                            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(_lastPage);
                            var existingPages = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
                        }
                    });

                    //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(); });
                }
                else if (root.payload?.data?.updatePassword != null)
                {
                    GlobalResources.WaitStop();
                    if (root.payload.data.updatePassword == true)
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Your password has been updated", "OK"); ; });
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Any(p => p is DabProfileManagementPage))
                            {
                                var existingPagess = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
                                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
                                var _lastPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
                                Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(_lastPage);
                                var existingPages = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
                            }
                        });

                        //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(); });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: you could set some sentinel variable that tracks how many requests are made, and then only pop when that many requests are completed.  Your current approach seems extremely convoluted for what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah that should definitely work. I was thinking something similar earlier but get worried about what would be best practice sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason pointed out I just added variable of type int and increased it after a pop happened and reset it once it tries to go past 2. I also reset it to 0 once the user clicks to open the page again. The only issue, which shouldn't happen often is if the user tries to go and change info for a third time without leaving the page. No pop will happen. I thought about adding a timer but I have had apps get messy with timers before so I opted to keep it as is for now. Hoping I do find a way to pop once every time no matter how many times the user decides to hit that function.

```
                else if (root.payload?.data?.updateUserFields != null)
                {
                    DabGraphQlUpdateUserFields fields = root.payload.data.updateUserFields;

                    dbSettings.StoreSetting("Email", fields.email);
                    dbSettings.StoreSetting("FirstName", fields.firstName);
                    dbSettings.StoreSetting("LastName", fields.lastName);

                    GlobalResources.WaitStop();
                    var UserName = GlobalResources.GetUserName().Split(' ');
                    GuestStatus.Current.UserName = GlobalResources.GetUserName();
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "User profile information has been updated", "OK"); ; });
                    if (popRequests < 1)
                    {
                        popRequests = popRequests + 1;
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(); });
                    }
                    else
                        popRequests = 0;
                }
                else if (root.payload?.data?.updatePassword != null)
                {
                    GlobalResources.WaitStop();
                    if (root.payload.data.updatePassword == true)
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Your password has been updated", "OK"); ; });
                        if (popRequests < 2)
                        {
                            popRequests = popRequests + 1;
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(); });
                        }
                        else
                            popRequests = 1;
                    }
                }
```